# macOS Catalina python via launchd access denied to Downloads folder

Tags: python-3.x, macos, permissions

I am having permission issues with a python program executed via script via launchd.

If I run the .sh script from Terminal, or from BBEdit, it executes OK.

When run from launchd, I get:

```
with open(_userHome + '/Downloads/quotes.csv', newline='') as chkFile:
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/xxx/Downloads/quotes.csv'
```

Permissions on the download folder give the user r/w and everyone read access.
I tried adding python3 to security with full disk access using /usr/local/bin/python3.

This is specific to the 'Downloads' folder. I created a 'Downloads2' folder and it worked fine. That is a terrible kluge. I should be able to use the default download folder.

Ideas ?

Comment: Show us `$ ls -ld ~/Downloads/` -- you've already done `$ chmod a+rwx` on it, yes? Are you launching as a **user** named python3, so `$ sudo -u python3 ls -ld Downloads` would be relevant?

Comment: Not running as python, running as me (User = Craig).   ls -ld ~/Downloads/ gives 
drwxr-xr-x+ 6 craig  staff  192 Nov 11 10:37 /Users/craig/Downloads/

Comment: The author of LauchControl, a macOS app for managing launchd jobs, has created a utility that allows jobs to be run via the utility, which wraps the script in a single authorized task. We are still testing it (going well), but it should be available in the next release of LaunchControl. Not sure if the util will be released separately. I use LaunchControl, I have no stake in it.

Answer (score 0):

You're running a newer, more restrictive version of MacOS than I am.

Refer to https://nektony.com/duplicate-finder-free/folders-permission

for advice that goes beyond `chmod a+r`.

Tl;dr: SysPref --> Security&Privacy --> Privacy --> Files&Folders --> +